# Splitting a long string on last whitespace or after max is exceeded

Tags: regex

I am trying to split a long string into smaller chunks based on a line limit. Given the following as an example

> This is a long header. It's long on purpose. It\'s purpose is to test that the splitting works correctly. It should be well over the line limit. If it is shorter then it would not test the limit.

If the line limit is 70 it should split into

> This is a long header. It's long on purpose. It's purpose is to test
>
> that the splitting works correctly. It should be well over the line
>
> limit. If it is shorter then it would not test the limit.

The regular expression I came up with is as follows but it has a problem.

```
(\S*?.{1,70}(\s|\Z))
```

https://regex101.com/r/Vr5QNZ/3/

If one word for some reason is too long it won't split because its only looking for whitespace. As an example, if I put the URL of this question in the string (removing the h in http so it actually displays)

> ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528045/large-string-split-into-lines-with-maximum-length-in-java
>    remark This is a long header. It's long on purpose. It's purpose is to test
>    remark that the splitting works correctly. It should be well over the line
>    remark limit. If it is shorter then it would not test the limit.

the output would be

> ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528045/large-string-split-into-lines-with-maximum-length-in-java
>
> This is a long header. It's long on purpose. It's purpose is to test
>
> that the splitting works correctly. It should be well over the line
>
> limit. If it is shorter then it would not test the limit.

That first line is well over the limit of 70 characters and since there is no whitespace to split on it just goes past the 70 characters. I would want it to split at a whitespace if there is one present before 70 characters are exhausted or if none are present, then split at the 70 character mark. The correct example would look something like

> ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528045/large-string-split-into-lin
>
> es-with-maximum-length-in-java This is a long header. It's long on
>
> purpose. It's purpose is to test that the splitting works
>
> correctly. It should be well over the line limit. If it is
>
> shorter then it would not test the limit.

Comment: Can you post a sample input text with expected output here

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/Vr5QNZ/5) help?

Comment: What are you trying to get? From the regex fiddle, it is not clear.

Comment: By "upper limit" do you mean split after the nth whitespace character, for a given `n` (unless..)? Also, I suggest you add a couple of examples, showing the desired result for each.

Comment: Sorry I did a poor job, I added an example showing what happens in a normal case and what happens when some large word that by itself is over the limit appears and the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question, but does this fix your problem: (\S*?[^ ]{1,70}(\s|\Z|))